# Textangular dropping attributes on UL element

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, textangular

I have the following HTML that I pull from a database and send to a view with a Text Angular control:

```
<ul class="support">
  <li class="lineitem">Hello world</li>
</ul>
```

When I first load the page, it appears correct:
[image: Rendered View]

When I switch to HTML view, the attributes on the UL element get dropped and the element hangs open:

[image: HTML View]

This happens for any attributes added to the UL element, ID, name, etc.  What do I need to set in order to allow attributes on the UL element?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. You can fix it with changing row in source code https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/blob/ff8e48087f780d30f54e77b06f09e0b85f9517e9/dist/textAngular.js#L2132

Original:

```
_html += _repeat('\t', tablevel-1) + listNode.outerHTML.substring(0, 4);
```

Replace with:

```
_html += _repeat('\t', tablevel - 1) + listNode.outerHTML.substring(0, listNode.outerHTML.indexOf('>') + 1);
```

There is a fork you can use and that has an open PR: https://github.com/textAngular/textAngular/pull/1573